# How to set default value for OpenERP v7 at form interface

Tags: odoo

Just started to dig into OpenERP v7. Previously at v6.1, default values at certain form can be easily define at the right side of each form. For e.g, Product Type I need to set it to "Stockable Product" as default rather than "Consumable", how can achieve this in v7?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to Use Web in Activate the "developer mode" then Debug Menu.
Use Following Steps :

- Go to User Context Menu (Upper Right Corner) and Click on **About OpenEEP**,
- Here you will find one Option **Active the Developer Mode** click on that URL, this will reload the Web and Now you will active debug mode.
- Goto Product list view and on top of Kanban VIew of Product you will find `Debug View#` option.
- Then Click on Create new Product and in **Product Type** Select the Stockble product and Now goto **Debug View#** and you will find **Set Defaults** Option and select your default and Save it.

Hope this will help.

Comment: This has been filed as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+bug/1081494).

Comment: @DReispt: That is related bug but that happens due to specific reason, which I can explain if you, here i just explain how Set Defaults works

Comment: Yes, of course. I upvoted your answer. I was just adding additional info on this.

Comment: On GTK client it was possible to set default for o2m fields...

How could this be done on web client?  o2m fields don't appear on available list of fields...

Answer (score 0):

Be aware if it is a field marked for translation, I'm experiencing very bad problems with values in those fields which are different in the partner table and in the translation table (I think this is a serious bug that should be fixed ASAP)